# Vue-router - How to add custom suffix to route param?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router, path-to-regexp

I have this route path

```
/custom/:length(\\d+-letter-)?words
```

It matches below routes as expected ✅

```
/custom/3-letter-words
/custom/words
```

However, **this.$route.params.length** returns **3-letter-**.

My expectation is that **this.$route.params.length** will return **3** as a result and the route path I entered will match both routes above.

In this case, how should I change the route path above? If you think that it won't work by changing the route path, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 path: "/custom/:length(\\d+)?-letter-words",
 alias: "/custom/words"
```

which would output the correct value for length, but this would also match `/custom/-letter-words`.

Unfortunately you can't use `:length(?:(\\d+)-letter-)?` with vue-router, it doesn't parse it correctly.

Another option would be to use [props](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) in function mode:

```
props: (route) => ({
        letterCount: route.params.length ?
          route.params.length.match(/^\d+/)[0] :
          null
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My personal opinion is that instead of sending it to the component as a prop, a plugin that parses the route.param should be injected into the project so that it can be used in all components.

Answer (score 0):

Vue-router uses path-to-regexp library for path matching and this library actually supports custom prefix and suffix: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-prefix-and-suffix

The problem here is that the version of this library that vue-router uses is old (v1.8.0) and this feature is not supported in this version. There is an opened issue on vue-router about this, but they said they won't do it because there is a breaking change in the new version.

So it seems that it is not possible to do this by structuring the path. Since the best practice method cannot be applied, of course, there may be different alternative ideas, but I personally prefer to get the variable while parsing the route.param.